# Solving Recurrence Relations with Geometric Series

Tags: calculus, recurrence-relations, computer-science

If given the following problem...
$$4T \left(\frac n2\right) + c$$
after getting the pattern down you see the following
$$4^k T\left(\frac {n}{2^k}\right) + 3^{k-1}c + 3^{k-2} c + \cdots + 3c + c$$

Then we factor out the common $c$ and determine it is a geometric series where $r>1$. So The following happens...
$$\sum_{i=1}^n r^i = \theta(r^n)$$
So we apply this to the current equation I get this...
$$4^k + c(4^{k-1} + 4^{k-2} + \cdots + 4 + 1)$$

So is the largest term $4^{k}$? If it is then, do ignore the resulting series? When I solve for $k$, I get $\log_2 n$ when stopping at $\frac {n}{2^k} = 1$. Then finally I plug this into the current problem and get this...$$4^{\log_2 n} + c(4^{\log_2 n -1} + 4^{\log_2 n - 2} + \cdots + 4 + 1)$$
Then I solve the issue with the non matching log base to below base and I get this $$4^{\log_2 n} = (2^{\log_2 4})^{\log_2 n}$$ which becomes the following $$n^{\log_2 4}$$ Is this correct? I get the run time as being either $\theta(n)$ or $\theta(n^{\log_2 4})$ . My guess is the time is still $\theta(n)$. Any thoughts?

Comment: I'm really not sure about how to handle geometric series when it comes to these type of problems. I just know common rules like $$\sum_{i=1}^{n} r^{i} = \theta(r^{n})$$ for $|r| > 1 $ and the other common rules I'm just not sure if my logic is correct when working with them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So we apply this to the current equation I get this...
>   $$4^k + c(4^{k-1} + 4^{k-2} + \cdots + 4 + 1)$$

You should get 
$$4^k~T(n 2^{-k}) + c(4^{k-1} + 4^{k-2} + \cdots + 4 + 1)$$

which for $k = \log_2(n)$ makes the leading term $4^k~T(1)$.

> So is the largest term $4^k$ ?

That depends on your initial conditions.  If $T(1)>0$, then yes.  Otherwise no.

But it doesn't matter anyway.  The entire point of asymptotic runtime is that scaling factors don't affect asymptotic runtime behavior.

$$O(x^2) = O(4x^2) = O(100000000000000x^2)$$

Since $4^k$ and $4^{k-1}$ only differ by a factor of $4$, either could be considered the largest term in the sum for purposes of runtime analysis.

> I get the run time as being either $\Theta(n)$ or $\Theta(n^{log_2 4})$

Keep in mind that $1 + x + x^2 + \dots + x^n$ is $\Theta(x^{n+1})$ for constant $x$.  So you should get:

$$\Theta\left(T(1)~4^{\log_2(n) + 1}\right)$$
$$\Theta\left(4~T(1)~4^{\log_2(n)}\right)$$
$$\Theta\left(4~T(1)~n^{\log_2(4)}\right)$$

Removing constant factors:

$$\Theta\left(n^2\right)$$

Comment: I'm just not sure how you got the $\theta(n^{2})$. I compared my original answer of $\theta(n^{\log_2 4})$ to the problem $T(n) = 3T(\frac{n}{2}) + c$, with test values like 1 2 3 4  for $n$ and both sides come out equal. That's why I'm confused :(

Comment: log base 2 of 4 is 2 so your answer is equivalent i guess...

Comment: @WilderField It seems like he wasn't sure if it was O(n)